# Make a topological torus-with-a-hole out of congruent squares that may share an edge or a vertex with other squares

Tags: geometry, construction, topology

Suppose we arrange, in 3-dimensional space, 8 identical solid cubes in space so they form a square-shaped ring (using a 3x3 arrangement of squares except for the one in the middle).

Its surface will be topologically a torus, composed of a total of 32 congruent squares, any two of which intersect each other along an entire common edge or a common vertex, or not at all.

If we now remove one of the 32 congruent squares, the 31 that remain will form a torus with a hole punched through it, and such that any two of the squares that intersect do so only along an entire common edge or a common vertex.

### Puzzle:

What is the smallest number of congruent squares that you can arrange in 3-dimensional space so that they form a topological torus with a hole punched through it, and such that any two squares that intersect each other do so along an entire common edge or along a common vertex?

Answer (score 2):

As a torus with a hole is the same (topologically) as an

> "8" shape

the answer should be

> 5

Comment: A torus with a hole is homotopy equivalent to what people usually call a figure 8, but the latter is 1-dimensional whereas the torus with a hole is 2-. I don't see how to arrange five squares to get something homeomorphic to a torus with a hole; can you specify, please?

Comment: @msh210: A picture would be nice, but basically it is like this: rot13(Fgneg jvgu svir fdhnerf va gur cynar neenatrq nf n Terrx pebff. Sbyq gjb bccbfvgr nezf hc bhg bs gur cynar naq fgvpx gurve raqf gbtrgure gb znxr n gevnathyne ghor. Sbyq gur bgure gjb nezf qbjajneqf naq pbaarpg gurz gb znxr n frpbaq gevnathyne ghor.)

Comment: Thanks,  @JaapScherphuis, couldn't have put it better myself.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis that'd work.

Comment: I picture the hole differently yet ^voted because i like wherever this answer leads no matter what puzzle it solves.

Comment: The posted answer can't be right because  — as msh210 wrote — a torus with a hole punched through it is 2-dimensional, not the same as an "8" shape. (Even though it is homotopy equivalent to an "8" shape.)

Comment: @DanielAsimov, msh210 I find it fascinating that there appears to be such a stringent and universally accepted definition of the informal "8" shape which I made all up as I went along. Maybe it's a boldface **8** and even if not every single eight I have encountered so far had nonvanishing thickness. It's all moot anyway since we are asked to work  with solid squares in the end.

Comment: A "figure-8" in topology almost always means the space created by glueing two circles together along a common point. It's not a technical term, but it's almost always interpreted this way.

Comment: But even if the "8" is thickened, then its boundary consists of three disjoint simple  closed curves. By contrast, the boundary of the torus with one hole in it is just *one* simple closed curve. So they cannot be topologically equivalent.